# How can we have Static website on front end Yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I want to create website in two modules 1st 5 static pages which is my existing website. Now I want to add database and login access for other pages which will be other module. So how can I use existing website on first load then clicking to sign in it will redirect to other module. I'm using Yii 1.1.14

Answer (score 1):

First, in the default SiteController (or other controller if you like), override the actions() method as follows,

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}
```

Second, create a folder protected/views/site/pages.

Third, save each static page as a PHP file under this folder. For example, we can save the "about this site" page as about.php. Note, these pages will use the application's default layout. Therefore, only the main content needs to be saved in each file.

We are done! To access a static page, e.g., the about page, we can use the following URL:

http://www.example.com/index.php?r=site/page&view=about

more detail in : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/